# Saturn Vue 07' 3.5L 62,000 idle

Tags: idle, stall

I was driving down the interstate and went over  A normal bump in the road and my car started to idle funny and my right turn signal light was week. Turn signals wouldn't work either. But when I hit a small bump again my car would work just fine and my turn signals also worked fine.  This happened a couple times I thought oh I'll have my dad look at it. Now my car don't move when you start it idles really low like it's sputtering you go to accelerate and it may or may not accelerate and it stalls out. Also My right turn signal has a weak light  and I go to put it in drive or reverse it stalls. No check engine light on. Hooked it up to a computer and no codes came up.

Comment: Could be a loose ground, anything obvious is an easy fix. Some ground points are pretty well hidden. Make sure the battery terminals are ok as well.

Comment: @Ben That should probably be a full answer.